# How to get client information at Tomcat server side application

Tags: tomcat, servlets

My tomcat server runs on YYYY machine and client runs on XXXX and whenever the request comes to YYYY, it processes the request sending the request to another machine.

```
My server.http looks like-->
<Service name="MyService">
    <Connector port="3096"
       maxThreads="50" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="50"
       debug="0" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="60000"
       enableLookups="true" address="YYYY"/>
    <Engine name="standalone" defaultHost="localhost">
```

The servlet which processes the request has the `getRemoteHost()` as "YYYY". Can anyone please give any light how can I get the client info (host and port)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about this. If not let me know more about that you want to know.

```
request.getRemoteAddr(); //Where the client is commong from => ip address.
request.getRemotePort(); //where the client is using port => port.
```